# GIT: error: pathspec 'xxx did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

I have some trouble with a git repository of mine and I cant find the error :(

Thing is, I had this repository already in use for a PHP project. everything was fine. Then, I "added" composer to it. I.e., I copied the composer file to the repositorie's root, created a composer.json, and used "composer install". Hence, composer.lock and vendor/ were created for me.

Since I didnt want those to be included in the repo, I added the following to the .gitignore

```
composer
composer.lock
vendor/
```

Now, whenever I use "git add" oder "git commit" from the root, I will get the following errors:

```
$ git commit * -m "fixed issue #123"
error: pathspec 'composer' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'composer.lock' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'vendor' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Obviously, the commit (or add) does not work so I have to manually specify files to add or commit. Bummer.

I cannot find the problem :( Anyone knows how to fix this?

BTW I am using git version 2.4.9 (Apple Git-60)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, years passed, new git versions were released, yet the problem still show up for me from time to time. The posted fixes unfortunately do not help. Yet, instead of committing with `git commit . -m "xyz"` doing a

`git commit -a -m "xyz"`

does wonders.

Cheers.

Answer (score 19):

I often have this problem if something has changed, added files to gitignore or something else. Maybe you have to rebuild the index.

**Updated:** added recursive and file param to `git rm`

In my case this worked:

**remove cached files** (only the paths are removed from the index, not the real files!!!)

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

**add all files to the index**

```
git add .
```

**commit**

```
git commit -m "hopefully fixed pathspec error"
```

**UPDATE:**
If this won't work, try the following:

- Get a new checkout from your repo
- remove `composer, composer.lock, vendor/` from your .gitignore
- run the above suggestion again
- move the folders `composer, composer.lock, vendor/` outside your repo
- add and commit, maybe add with `-A` to add that the files are deleted
- add `composer, composer.lock, vendor/` to your .gitignore and commit
- move back the folders `composer, composer.lock, vendor/` to your repo

Now it should be gone from the repo and due to your .gitignore, never will be commited again. Hopefully the pathspec error is gone :)

Comment: Well seems like it worked just for one commit. Now, I get the EXACT same errors again. And this time, the fix does not work :(

Comment: can you try `git add -A` instead of `git add .`?

Comment: tried, didnt help :( also created a completely new repo and copied the files there (not .git* though) - same problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this - again. I tried this, but I end up with the EXACT same error :( Will try again later though. Maybe I made some mistake at some point...

Comment: Hey no problem, if you have a solution I would be glad if you post this here as an answer

Comment: ok i did the following now: 1) checked out a completely new version of the repo 2.) removed the items from .gitignore 3.) ran your suggestion 4.) no need to (re)move the folders/files (composer, composer.lock and vendor/) since they are not in the repository 5.) git add -A * && git commit * -m "x" 6.) added "the files" to .gitignore again 7.) copied composer into the dir and ran ./composer install (i.e. created the "missing" files). 8.) git add -A * && git commit * -m "y". THIS worked again for exactly ONE commit, but after that the SAME error showed up again :(

Comment: I did as swidmann says in his last update but instead of git add . , I did git add -A . And after that It worked for next commit and all the future commit too... :D

Comment: @Jaythaking, glad to hear, that it finally worked for someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue due to how many levels deep (length) my folders were. The path name was too long and git couldn't handle it, so I took the folder and threw it on my C: and everything started working fine. Check to see if your folder structure is too long. Ex:

`C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/..../folder99/file.txt`

above is too long, try to make it much shorter.
Something like `C:/folder1/folder2/file.txt` (For all files in the repo) and this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

GIT: error: pathspec "git checkout  did not match any file(s) known to git

For this error I used **git fetch origin** command and then tried to checkout to my desired branch and the error got resolved.

Hope this helps others!!