# How to revert deleted file in git?

Tags: git, composer-php

I've deleted my `composer.lock` file and didn't commit yet.

`git checkout -- composer.lock`

gives

> error: pathspec 'composer.lock' did not match any file(s) known to git.

How do I restore the `composer.lock` file?

Comment: I suggest googling the error message. For example, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628862/git-error-pathspec-xxx-did-not-match-any-files-known-to-git

Comment: Is your `composer.lock` being ignored in the `.gitignore` file? Did you add and commit `composer.lock` at least once before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git reset -- composer.lock`

Also this a duplicate of [this exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591407/unstage-a-deleted-file-in-git/9591612). Please look here to get better insight.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah, it was staged, by this command I unstaged it, and then checkout  from index